# calculate the number of terms in the expansions which do not have ordered exponentials like $(0,1,2,3,4,...)$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-theorem

I know that there are $11$ terms in the expansion of $(x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)^2$  . Moreover there are much related question about it when the elements are ordered without having any missing element.

My question will be about those which have "missing terms" . For example , the number of elements in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5+x^6)^3$ is equal to $19$. Then,

> How many terms are there in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^6)^3$ ? (Answer is $17$)

Is there any general method for those ?

For a second example :

> How many terms are there in the expansion of $(1+x+x^2+x^6)^3$ ? (Answer is $15$)

Concisely , I am looking for the method which provide me to calculate the number of terms in the expansions which do not have ordered exponentials like $(0,1,2,3,4,...)$ etc.

I hope to find mathematical approach instead of offering worlfram alpha..

Comment: Combinatorial, this is the same as “If I have a four-sided die with the numbers $0,1,2,6$ on the faces, how many possible totals when rolling the die $3$ times.”  I don’t think it has a useful general solution. The maximum number of terms for $p(x)^k$ here $p(x)$ is the sum of $n$ distinct $x^i$ is $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}.$

Comment: This is reminding me of a graduate level little book by Paul Stanley, “Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra.” It uses homological algebra to do certain counting questions, as an advanced form of inclusion-exclusion.